# Excel If duplicate agree paste the value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

could you please help me with this in excel formula.

I have a table with duplicate if the duplicate value agree I want to copy the value if duplicate values do not agree I want to copy the one which has the value.

Input

| Name | M1 | M2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MO-118 | 0.8274% | 1.3 |
| MO-118 | 0.8274% | 1.3 |
| MO-26 | 0.0012% | 4.1 |
| MO-26 | 0 |  |

Output

| Name | header 2 | M2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MO-118 | 0.8274% | 1.3 |
| MO-26 | 0.0012% | 4.1 |

Thanks
Sara

```
=IF(ROWS(G$5:G5)<=COUNTIF(Table1[Salesman],G$4),INDEX(D$5:D$16,SMALL(IF(C$5:C$16=G$4,ROW(Table1[Salesman])-4),ROWS(G$5:G5))),””)
```

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365:

```
=LET(
    nm,A2:A5,
    m_1,B2:B5,
    M_2,C2:C5,
    unq,UNIQUE(nm),
    HSTACK(unq,MAXIFS(m_1,nm,unq),MAXIFS(M_2,nm,unq)))
```

[image]